# Merge sort on K-Sorted Array

Tags: sorting, merge

I want to sort a nearly sorted array ( K-sorted Array )

I tried to change a little bit my merge sort to try “divide and conquer” method with the nearly sorted array , I don’t understand why my code crash for (k = 1) it is really weird I check if I am calling wrong emplacement or dividing by 0 but didn’t find any issues with the debugger …

```c
void internal_msort(int a[], int n, int helper_array[],int k)
{
    int left = n / (k),right = n - left; // this is the line where its crash
    if (n < k)
        return;
    internal_msort(a, left, helper_array,k);
    internal_msort(a + left, right, helper_array,k);
    merge(a, left, a + left, right, helper_array);
    memcpy(a, helper_array, n * sizeof(int));
}

void merge_sort(int a[], int n,int k)
{
    int *tmp_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    internal_msort(a, n, tmp_array,k);
    free(tmp_array);
}
```

it works fine for k != 1

For example i have :

```
Please enter a non negative integer (k):1
Please enter a non negative integer (n):10
Please enter n integer values with the special characteristic:
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

Process finished with exit code 11
```

Comment: Where **exactly** does it crash? Is there any further information given about the crash?

Comment: its crash on the internal msort : Process finish with exit code 11

Comment: And by using which parameters does that process crash?

Comment: @NicoHaase what does it means ? its for k=1 its crash

Comment: That's the only input parameter? Then it looks obvious to me: `internal_msort` needs three of them

Comment: ah no i tested for for n=10,k=1 and a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

Comment: Please add this information to the question itself, including the exact line that triggers the crash

Comment: @NicoHaase u have an idea ?